# jQuery accordion show/hide on current container

Tags: jquery, accordion, show-hide

I have created an accordion for an FAQ page, I have managed to get the questions/answers to show/hide when clicked, when you click a question all others hide and the current question is opened.

The only issue is if you try to close the current opened question the heading remains highlighted as it is still defined as the current question.

How can I fix this?

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1cqk1540/1/

**jQuery:**

```
// Hide the answers (expanded content)
$(".content .accordion span").hide();

// On question click
$(".content .accordion .question").click(function(){
    // If the next element to the question is visible
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        // Slide the answer up
        $('.content .accordion span').slideUp(300);
    }

    // Toggle the slide of the next element to the question
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);

    // Remove current class from the previous accordion container
    $('.content .accordion.current').removeClass('current');

    // Remove current class from the current accordion container
    $(this).parent().addClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I changed:

```js
$('.content .accordion.current').not($(this).parent().toggleClass('current')).removeClass('current');
```

The one that was clicked is using the `toggleClass` function, and the others are all using the `removeClass` function.

**Demo:**

```js
// Hide the answers (expanded content)

$(".content .accordion span").hide();

// On question click

$(".content .accordion .question").click(function() {

  // If the next element to the question is visible

  if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {

    // Slide the answer up

    $('.content .accordion span').slideUp(300);

  }

  // Toggle the slide of the next element to the question

  $(this).next().slideToggle(300);

  // Remove current class from the previous accordion container

  $('.content .accordion.current').not($(this).parent().toggleClass('current')).removeClass('current');

  // Remove current class from the current accordion container 

});
```

```css
.accordion {
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px
}

.accordion.current .question {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.accordion .question {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}

.accordion span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#q" class="question">Q1 Aenean varius tincidunt arcu?</a>
    <span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mollis, ipsum id aliquet ornare, nibh leo luctus turpis, sed consectetur libero diam et est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec nibh arcu, porttitor at finibus id, consectetur ac nunc. Aenean varius tincidunt arcu, ac egestas quam posuere eu. Maecenas congue mollis mattis. Quisque sollicitudin lectus consectetur mi auctor, ac feugiat velit convallis.</p>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <a href="#q" class="question">Q2 Aenean varius tincidunt arcu?</a>
    <span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mollis, ipsum id aliquet ornare, nibh leo luctus turpis, sed consectetur libero diam et est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec nibh arcu, porttitor at finibus id, consectetur ac nunc. Aenean varius tincidunt arcu, ac egestas quam posuere eu. Maecenas congue mollis mattis. Quisque sollicitudin lectus consectetur mi auctor, ac feugiat velit convallis.</p>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what the new line does: If current accordion is not immediate parent of current accordion (same accordion) toggle the current class, if current class is set then it gets removed?

Comment: All elements who has the class `current` gets the class removed. Except the one who was clicked (`.not()`), that one gets a toggle. Depends if the accordion is open yes or not. If you want I can write it in less code, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

you for every click add class .current. correct code https://jsfiddle.net/xbh7bx02/

```
 if( !$( this ).parent().hasClass( 'current' ) )
    {
        $('.content .accordion.current').removeClass('current');
      // Remove current class from the current accordion container
      $(this).parent().addClass('current');
    } else {
        $('.content .accordion.current').removeClass('current');
      // Remove current class from the current accordion container
    }
```